# from python aws-lambda how to read files on S3 bucket using GeoPandas reader?

Tags: amazon-s3, io, aws-lambda, boto3, geopandas

There is a lot of literature on the topic but none of those I could find use a GeoPandas reader.

My code purpose is to identify if a point is located into a polygone described in a .shp file stored in S3. It's then expected to return a boolean True or False.

I use python-lambda-local python module to test my python script located on PyCharm.

```
import geopandas as gpd
from geopandas.geoseries import *
import boto3
from io import BytesIO


def search(event, context):
    dep = event['Dep']
    arr = event['Arr']

    point_1 = GeoSeries(dep)
    point_2 = GeoSeries(arr)

    s3 = boto3.client("s3")

    bucket = "mybucket"
    obj_key = "filename.shp"

    # bytes_buffer = BytesIO()
    # client.download_fileobj(Bucket=bucket, Key=obj_key, Fileobj=bytes_buffer)

    obj = s3.download_file(Bucket=bucket, Key="filename.shp", Filename=obj_key)
    geo = obj['body'].read().decode('ISO-8859-9')

    # geo = bytes_buffer.get_key(obj_key).get_contents_as_string()

    answer = gpd.read_file(geo)
    print(answer)
```

As you can see in the code, I tried a few different lines to use IO and the reader() in different ways. Always unsuccessfully though.

```
#And this is the error message:#

MacBook-Pro:IdPolygons me$ python-lambda-local -l lib/ -f search  -t 4 IdAircraft.py event.json

*This is the point I'm trying to identify inside or outside the polygon:*
[root - INFO - 2019-12-24 07:33:54,388] Event: {'Dep': '(40.7128, 74.0060)', 'Arr': '(48.8566, 2.3522)'} 

[root - INFO - 2019-12-24 07:33:54,388] START RequestId: 629c76c7-1008-40cc-8c09-6c5dd3877125 Version: 
[botocore.credentials - INFO - 2019-12-24 07:33:54,923] Found credentials in shared credentials file: ~/.aws/credentials stored 
[root - INFO - 2019-12-24 07:33:55,576] END RequestId: 629c76c7-1008-40cc-8c09-6c5dd3877125
[root - INFO - 2019-12-24 07:33:55,577] REPORT RequestId: 629c76c7-1008-40cc-8c09-6c5dd3877125  Duration: 663.91 ms
[root - INFO - 2019-12-24 07:33:55,577] RESULT:
{
    "errorMessage": "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'",
    "stackTrace": [
        "  File \"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lambda_local/main.py\", line 153, in execute\n    result = func(event, context._activate())\n",
        "  File \"IdAircraft.py\", line 30, in search\n    df1 = gpd.read_file(obj)\n",
        "  File \"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/geopandas/io/file.py\", line 77, in read_file\n    with reader(path_or_bytes, **kwargs) as features:\n",
        "  File \"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fiona/env.py\", line 397, in wrapper\n    return f(*args, **kwargs)\n",
        "  File \"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fiona/__init__.py\", line 249, in open\n    path = parse_path(fp)\n",
        "  File \"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fiona/path.py\", line 132, in parse_path\n    elif path.startswith('/vsi'):\n"
    ],
    "errorType": "AttributeError"
}
```

Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: One point which might help. Shp is not one file only, it is composed of at least 3 files (shp, shx, dbf), so downloading shp only will not work anyway. Try zip it or get all of them. However, not sure if that is causing the issue above.

Comment: thanks @martinfleis, yes I am aware and did that. Still not having it work.